# Why after pyinstaller finished .exe, all stdouts of subprocess were printed to QTextBrower at once?

Tags: python-2.7

Pycharm can run correctly my code, which print subprocess stdout one by one to qt widget (QTextBrower), but after pyinstaller to .exe, it will print all stdouts at once till the subprocess finished, that is not a expected result

I tried use flush() and stdout.close in the subprocess, still the same.

class NonBlockingStreamReader:

```
def __init__(self, stream):
    self._s = stream
    self._q = Queue()

    def _populateQueue(stream, queue):           
        while True:
            line = stream.readline()
            if line:
                queue.put(line)
            #else:
                #raise UnexpectedEndOfStream

    self._t = Thread(target = _populateQueue, args = (self._s, self._q))
    self._t.daemon = True
    self._t.start() #start collecting lines from the stream

def readline(self, timeout=None):
    try:
        return self._q.get(block=timeout is not None, timeout=timeout)

    except Empty:
        return None
```

......

form = uic.loadUiType("data/GUI/GUI.ui")[0]

class Form(QtGui.QDialog, form):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):

    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    os.chdir("../../")       
    self.LogAnalyzeButton.clicked.connect(self.LogAnalyzePre)
```

......

```
def LogAnalyzePre(self):
    self.Console.append("Analyzing log, please wait . . . . . . ." + "\n" )
    arguments = 'python log.py %s'%(path)
    self.proc = Popen(arguments, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    nbsr = NonBlockingStreamReader(self.proc.stdout)
    while self.proc.poll() is None:
        line = nbsr.readline(0.1)
        print line
        if line:
            self.Console.insertPlainText(unicode(line, "utf-8"))
            self.Console.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

when run .exe, I can see the debug cmd window show that line's value is always None, and till the subprocess closed, the stdouts in queue are print at once

Answer (score 0):

This has been proved it is a mistake that I did't put the log.py which had been added a flush() method into the same folder with .exe, so the flush() method can definitely solve this stdout output issue